# Vue.js this.$el.getContext('2d') is not a function

Tags: chart.js, vuejs2

I'm fooling around with Vue.js Version 2 and Charts.js to create a component that I can pass data to and it will display those in a nice way. This is my Code:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <canvas width="900" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['customers','dates'],
        mounted() {
            console.log('Chart-Component mounted.');
            var context = this.$el.getContext('2d');
            console.log(context);
            var myChart = new Chart(context, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: this.dates,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: this.customers,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 3,
                        cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone',
                        lineTension: 0
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero:true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
</script>
```

If I give the canvas an id and get the context via:

```
document.querySelector('#graph').getContext('2d');
```

it works quite fine but then I can use my component only once which is obviously not what I want. So I tried to get the context via:

```
this.$el.getContext('2d');
```

but then I get the following error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.$el.getContext is not a function"

I googled and checked the doc, but to be honest I'm really new to vue and I'm not really sure what I could search for anymore...

So if anyone could help me out or could tell me what I should check out next it would be highly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: are you using weex-chart and weex-gcanvas plugin? Do you have any example code to share how to use it ? The official one doesn't work any longer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this.$el` in this case is a reference to `div#container`. What you want to do is use a [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref).

> ref is used to register a reference to an element or a child
> component. The reference will be registered under the parent
> component’s $refs object

```
<div class="container">
  <canvas ref="canvas" width="900" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

And then

```
this.$refs.canvas.getContext('2d')
```